# Deliver bytes to another application which calls ::recv()

Tags: c++, performance, sockets, linux-kernel, network-programming

I have a userspace C++ application (could be a library) processing packets.

I have a second application (written in C) which obtains bytes via calling `::recv()`.

1. Is it possible to "deliver" the processed packet bytes to the second application, without changing the code calling `::recv()`?
2. I'd also like to "divert" calls from `::send()` to the first application. I think I can do this using a dynamic library and `LD_PRELOAD`, but is it possible to do via a static technique?

Comment: What socket does it call ::recv on?

Comment: @user253751 I want to say they will all be the same socket, but if I'm processing in userspace, there won't be sockets? So they are both handling packets from/to the same destination?

Comment: Well the application is calling recv, recv works on sockets, so either the second application is calling recv on a socket or else it's really dumb.

Comment: @user253751 You asked "what socket", not "is it using a socket"

Comment: Then you said there wouldn't be sockets. I don't understand that? recv receives bytes from sockets, nothing else.

Comment: @user253751 My understanding is "socket" is a kernel term? So if the first application is processing packets in userspace, say DPDK, I didn't think it would have a socket in the typical sense? Hence my original comment. Hope this makes sense now?

Comment: Yes, "socket" is something in the kernel and "recv" is call to the kernel to ask it to get data from a "socket". "recv" calls the kernel and asks for data from a "socket"; it never asks for data from DPDK.

Comment: What is the first application doing with the packets, that would cause them to go to the second application?

Comment: @user253751 First application is 100% my code, parsing packets, timestamps etc. Second "application" is actually a third party library consuming the data, hence I don't want to change the code. Could I have my application modify the Linux system call table entry for `recv()`? So the library calls `recv()` but it invokes a function within my application? Would this system call table change be "seen" by the third party library at runtime?

Comment: (or alternatively I use LD_PRELOAD, create a new definition for `recv()` in my application and so the library ends up calling it that way)

Comment: I think that is the way to do it - LD_PRELOAD. Note the application might also use `read` and `write`.

Comment: or maybe you override `connect` instead, so that the socket connects to your network process, instead of where it's actually supposed to connect to

Comment: @user253751 That might be possible but wouldn't recv() have to go in the kernel (like normal), for the socket to be read, for the redirection (to my app) to occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you want to be able to run any unmodified program in a special mode where all its sockets get connected to your own program which emulates the network, instead of the actual network. This is to help develop some custom networking code.

Perhaps the simplest way to do this is with LD_PRELOAD - a mechanism that is often used for overriding standard library functions.

You can make a shared library with function names like `recv` and `send`, and anything else you need to override, and then set the environment variable `LD_PRELOAD=my_socket_library.so` (change it to the actual filename) when running the second program. The loader will link `recv` and `send` calls to your functions instead of the ones in libc, because LD_PRELOAD libraries take priority. If you want to call the original functions you can use `dlsym` iwth `RTLD_NEXT` to get pointers to them (out of scope; Google for more information).

Alternatively, you might prefer to make it a real socket, connected to your networking program. Your networking program would listen on some port (using the kernel networking system) and your shared library would override the `connect` function so it connects to the port where the networking program was listening, then tells the networking program the address. Unless the program uses `getpeername` to see the address it's connected to (and most programs don't, because they already know which address they connected to) it won't know the difference, but since it's a real socket it would work no matter what socket stuff the the program did.

Comment: Is it possible for my own program to hijack the syscall table, from userspace?

Comment: @intrigued_66 absolutely not. However, it is possible to catch system calls, skip them and pretend they ran by using ptrace (like how the strace program works, but instead of just printing the system calls, you skip over them and simulate them) and I don't know if it's also possible with seccomp-bpf. Either one is more work than LD_PRELOAD.

Comment: Is it correct `::recv()` uses dynamic linking already because i think it's part of glibc? Which is dynamically linked

Comment: @intrigued_66 Yes, it uses the one in glibc